# Java array sort word print only two from the list

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I needed to have 10 user input words and arrange them into alphabetical order. I managed to sort the whole list of words, but the output should only be the first and the last words of the sorted list.

I have no idea how to get to the last part. (first & the last word, I only know how to print the whole list of words)

```
package words;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class words {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = new String[10];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 10 words in the array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        words[i] = in.next();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (words[j].compareTo(words[j + 1]) > 0) {
                String temp = words[j];
                words[j] = words[j + 1];
                words[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("words in alphaebatical order: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Input:

> dog cat bird pig zebra wolf giraffe smile sun animal

Output:

> bird zebra

Comment: The first word is the first element with index number 0 and the last is words.length - 1. Like System.out.println(words[0] +" and "+ words[words.length-1]);

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your IDE? I would add println statements so I could see what each step of the algorithm was doing.

Answer (score 2):

To print the first and last indexes of the array all you need to do is:

```
// word at first index
System.out.println("First word : " + words[0]); 

// word at last index (size - 1) as index start at 0
System.out.println("Last word : " + words[words.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] words = getWords(10);
    Arrays.sort(words);

    System.out.println("First word : " + words[0]);
    System.out.println("Last word : " + words[words.length - 1]);
}

public static String[] getWords(int total) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Enter 10 words in the array: ");

        String[] words = new String[total];

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
            words[i] = scan.next();

        return words;
    }
}
```